# undocumented CHARSET built-in variable in php?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

In the osCommerce PHP sources in every script there is a line like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
      content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>
```

The built-in variable "CHARSET" is very strange and I've never seen this in PHP programming before. I've tried extensive search for "CHARSET php apache encoding charset utf-8 osCommerce" with google, stackoverflow and of course in php.net but couldn't find any results about this PHP variable.

I need further information because it types out unexpected/wrong content which doesn't fit to file encoding, apache transmission encoding nor charset/locale on the system.

So I want to ask: Where does CHARSET get its content from? Do you know any documentation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/321294-where-to-define-charset/

Or read it here, as I've copied it from there... :P

Its in `catalog/includes/languages/english.php`. Change `english.php` to the language file you need. Look for:

```
// charset for web pages and emails
define('CHARSET', 'iso-8859-1');
```

Comment: Wouldn’t you rather have `UTF-8` there?

Comment: @tchrist: It will be little difference for the English localization. I expect the `languages/japenese.php` file to contain something different to `iso-8859-1` :P.

Comment: Well... I guess I misunderstand the purpose of the charset then. Isn’t it so that you can emit text in that encoding? If so, you’d want it for English nearly as much as anything else. I use curly quotes and dashes and such all the time. I hate using escapes for them because it’s hard to read.

Comment: @tchrist: apparently the default is already UTF-8 (at least in 2.3.1).